# How to read the data from text file in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

How do I read data from a text file in Prolog? Is there any example of file reading in SWI-prolog?

Answer (score 1):

```
readfacts:-
    open('example.txt',read,In),
    repeat,
    read_line_to_codes(In,X),writef(" "),
    writef(X),nl,
    X=end_of_file,!,
    nl,
    close(In).
```

Answer (score -1):

Prolog has a number of input/output predicates, falling into two categories: the [new ISO ones](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%274.16.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29) or the [old ones](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%274.16.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29) compatible with Edinburgh and DEC 10 versions. For full details including example code, see the reference manual following above links.